# Typo3: jQuery $(document).ready() not called, but scripts are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have an issue with an extbase frontend plugin where I list, edit and create new domain model entries. The problem is that in the "list" action of the controller the $(document).ready() function is called, but when I navigate to the "new" Action in the controller the $(document).ready() is not called but the scripts are loaded as seen in firebug. the version is TYPO3 6.2.15.

The scripts are added in setup.txt and are loaded into the page.
Also, there are no errors in the browser console.

Thank you.

Comment: If it is a single page app, document.ready does not wait for the new content to load it will just fire. Is that the case that it is running before the content is added? And depending on how scripts are added to the page, they may not be evaluated. Hard to tell since I have no clue what extbase is.

Comment: It is not a single page application. It uses the Typo3 CMS, and the code that i am running is part of an Extbase extension plugin. The problem is that the scripts are loaded in the browser, but only the .ready function is not called. On the list page, the same scripts are loaded and .ready is called, but not on the new page. Also, the page is loaded, and window.onload is called.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of $ use the keyword jQuery.

`jQuery(document).ready();`

Comment: It does not work with jQuery(document).ready() either, i can use $ instead of jQuery in the console of the browser and no error is given